# Font Identify: Folland, Real Analysis

Tags: fonts

I hope my question is proper to tex.se.

I add an image, but I am not sure if it is identifiable.

Is it possible to find a similar template to this book?

[image: Folland, Real Analysis]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately font identification is off-topic here. If you got a PDF example you might want to look into the PDF properties (with only an image it will be harder and you should ask somewhere where this is on-topic).

Comment: You can also try [What the Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Comment: Thank a lot. Is it proper to delete the question?

Comment: OT -- but pretty sure that text is times and math is computer modern. Try `\usepackage{newtxtext}`, leaving math as it is.

Comment: I concur with @PaulStanley. You get the (bad) typesetting with `\usepackage{times}`, but I wouldn't recommend it, because Times for text and Computer Modern for math form an incompatible pairing.