# Identifying and/or imitating a Times compatible math font from Conway's Functional Analysis

Tags: fonts, formatting, times, timesfont

I have been attempting to locate the name of the times-compatible math font present in John Conway's 1990 text [*A Course in Functional Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387972455).

[image: Theorem 5.5 from "A First Course in Functional Analysis" by Conway]

Other posts on this website, such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9685/math-and-times-font) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428029/font-identify-folland-real-analysis) have suggested `mathptmx`, `newtxtext`, and similar times-compatible math fonts. This font also does not appear in the large survey of free math fonts, found [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf). The most "times compatible" math font in my opinion, `mtpro2`, does not even match this style, as seen in the reproduction below.

[image: Reproduction of Theorem 5.5 using MathTimePro2]

Particularly, all of these packages mentioned miss one, if not all of the distinctive features I am looking to obtain in a times-compatible math font, but if that is not possible, reproduce with some coding:

1. The straight integral sign looking like the one that appears in the textbook.
2. The variation of the letter *g* (all the times-compatible math fonts have the "loop-tail" version of *g*, I would like to reproduce a times-compatible "fish hook" *g*, which is the one appearing in this font.)
3. An unswashed *z* (like the one appearing in this font and in the mtpro2 reproduction, there is no swashy tail.) This is not shown in the screenshot below, but you can see an example in the Amazon book preview linked above.

While there are more characteristics of this font, **these are the three things I would like to reproduce the most** if the mathematics font name cannot be identified.

If you would like to see more textbooks where this math font is used, it is also used in *[Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387906134)* (1982), and more recently [*Commutative Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387942696) (1995).

I hope I've made my question clear. To summarize, I would like to identify the math font used in Conway, but if that is not possible, code in at least the three times-compatible symbols (straight integral sign like the one that appears, the hooked-letter *g*, and unswashed *z*) listed above.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This looks to me suspiciously like it was produced with phototype, not a digital font output on a laser printer.  (The giveaway is the fact that "fi" does not appear to be ligatured.)  Thus it may not be identical to any of the Times-compatible fonts currently available.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton for the speedy response. I'm going to keep this question up in case someone is able to identify an "option" for a font package that produces it, or, can perhaps provide the code that will produce the listed characteristics.